# React Native: How to implement something like height: auto so that the image covers the view in width but doesn't stretch

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to add an image into a view in react native and I want the image to cover the entire width of the view so I added `width: '100%'` in my styles, but I needed to enter the height in integers for the image to show up. This is how my code looks like:

```
const SplashScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Splash Screen</Text>
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/Login.png')}
                style={styles.logo}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default SplashScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logo: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: 300,
        resizeMode: 'contain',  
    }
}
```

I want to use something like `height:auto` instead of hard coding `height:300`

This is how the vies should look like:

[image]

Thank you all

EDIT: For anyone else wondering, I just added a `height:'100%'` to `styles.container` and then I simply can adjust the height of the image using `flex`

example:

```
logo: {
        flex: 0.5,
        width: '100%',
        resizeMode: 'contain', 
        backgroundColor: 'red' 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just skip giving the 'height' to your container and also in the image as well.
you will have the dynamically required height

```
    logo: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        aspectRatio:1 //If you know your aspect ratio use this or else divide your image width and height to get it..
        //height: 300, Commenting or removing this will make dynamically resize
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    }
```

In your image tag add this attribute if you don't know your image aspect ratio `style={{ aspectRatio: image.width / image.height }`

Comment: Removing the height completely removes the image from the screen

Comment: use aspect ratio